# Matplotlib savefig() saving plots as blank images

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save graphs in folders I'm creating and they all show within Jupyter notebook but save as blank images within my folders.
This is my code:

```
    munilist = ["Adjuntas", "Anasco", "Ciales", "Jayuya", "Lares", "LasMarias", "Maricao", "Mayaguez", "Orocovis", "Penuelas", "Ponce", "SabanaGrande", "SanGerman", "SanSebastian", "Utuado", "Yauco"]
    for municipality in munilist:
        
        x = np.array([1987, 1992, 1998, 2002, 2007, 2012]).reshape(6,1)
        y = np.array(df[df["Municipio"]==municipality].iloc[0, 1:7]).reshape(6,1)
        print(y)
        mask = ~pd.isnull(y) #creating a mask to get rid of NaN columns values in certain csvs
        print(mask)
        xlin = np.arange(1987, 2013,1) #range of years to plot
        reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(x[mask].reshape(-1,1), y[mask])
        a0 = reg.intercept_
        a1 = reg.coef_[0]

        fit = a0 + a1*xlin #fitted value

        b0 = float(a0) #f strings do not accept array. Need to convert to float
        b1 = float(a1)
        eq = f"$farms = ${b0:.3f} $+$ {b1:.3f}$*year$"

        plt.scatter(x,y, label = name)
        plt.title(municipality)
        plt.plot(xlin, fit, 'r', label = "fitted line")
        plt.xlabel("Year")
        plt.ylabel(name)
        plt.text(2000,1000, eq)
        plt.legend()
        plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3)) #had to change figure size because they were coming out way too large
        if not os.path.isdir("RegressionsOutput/" + municipality):
            os.makedirs("RegressionsOutput/" + municipality)
        plt.savefig("RegressionsOutput/" + municipality + "/" + name + '.png', format="png", dpi=300, bbox_inches = 'tight') #save before showing
        plt.show()
```

[This is what saves in my folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA9jl.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `plt.figure(figsize=...)` after having done all of the work. This will reset the figure. Just move this line to the top so that it looks like

```
eq = f"..."
plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
...
plt.savefig(...)
```

I'm 95% sure this is your problem.

`plt.figure()` is designed to be used to create a *new* figure, so you will be overwriting any work you've done.

Comment: Indeed -- it's confusing because `plt.scatter()` makes its own figure, so that's what the OP is seeing in the notebook. Matplotlib 'helping'.

Comment: Yep, I'm actually curious because it seems like OP is saving the blank figure, maybe returning the prev figure to the current plt scope. This behaviour is like one of those super weird edge cases where everything looks to be working but only because of a very unlucky confluence of events. I'm not so sure how matplotlib decides what figure to reference when I say to `plt.do_something()`

Comment: because of that ambiguity, you should capture figure and axes objects (`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`) and do `ax.do_something`.  pyplot is a convenience interface, but it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly define the figure (e.g. "fig") initially (i.e. prior to plt.scatter()):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), num=1, clear=True)
```

and then show:

```
plt.show()
```

and then save:

```
fig.savefig("RegressionsOutput/" + municipality + "/" + name + '.png', ...)
```